# Where does the UID come from when implementing presence in Cloud Firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I searched for a long time on presence topic, and i found the following doc

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence.

I followed the doc and made all the necessary settings , but there is something i did not understand it .

in previous link, Specifically on the `.js code` for Firebase function they written the following

```
// Create a new function which is triggered on changes to /status/{uid}
// Note: This is a Realtime Database trigger, *not* Firestore.
exports.onUserStatusChanged = functions.database.ref('/status/{uid}').onUpdate(
    async (change, context) => {...etc...}
```

i need to understand how they got the uid value in `.ref('/status/{uid}')`??

i know that `status` is parent for uid child but how they can access it's value within `.ref('/status/{uid}')`

I spent three hours reviewing the document, but I couldn't figure out how they got uid value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first code snippet in the solution guide on [using Cloud Functions and Realtime Database to build presence on Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence#web) shows the code that writes the presence information to the Realtime Database:

```
// Fetch the current user's ID from Firebase Authentication.
var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

// Create a reference to this user's specific status node.
// This is where we will store data about being online/offline.
var userStatusDatabaseRef = firebase.database().ref('/status/' + uid);
...
```

So this code determines the UID of the user that is signed in, and then writes the presence information to the path `/status/$uid` in the Realtime Database. This then triggers the Cloud Function that you included, which picks the UID part of the path up here:

```
exports.onUserStatusChanged = functions.database.ref('/status/{uid}').onUpdate(
  ...
```

So this Cloud Function triggers whenever a user updates the status node, and takes the `uid` value that the client has written, so that is can write the presence information under the same UID to Firestore.

Comment: thank you , kindly can i change .ref('/status/{uid}' to any child name i want lets say  to .ref('/users/userId' Or it is fixed ?

Comment: The parameter name is free to choose, similar to how you can pick any name for a variable in your code (as long as you use the same name for it everywhere). To learn more about this, I recommend studying the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events